# How to get the dialled number in parallel calling in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I want to set up a parallel calling dialplan in asterisk.I have searched a bit and found that we can call parallel in asterisk with the below command.

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(DAHDI/g0/${NUMBER1}&DAHDI/g0/${NUMBER2})
```

So what i understood that asterisk server calls both number paralelly which one picks first the call is connected to that person and other hangup.

My problem in that how do i get the number which picks the call.Is there any variable to get the dialled number?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean? you want to put some conditions based on the incoming number?

Comment: @AlexGreg i just want the dialled number(NUMBER1 or NUMBER2) in parallel calling which picks the call(how do i get that in my dialplan), after `exten => _X.,1,Dial(DAHDI/g0/${NUMBER1}&DAHDI/g0/${NUMBER2})
` i want to save the number (which picks the call) to database

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+csv)

Comment: AlexGred, in cdr will be dialstring with both numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on-answer-macro  - M option of dial command to put any info into cdr.

Also you probably re-inventing queue with queue_log.